# Postgresql triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is it possible to see the last entry into a table that was triggered on?

For instance, I have a table called "users" and a table called "log".  I want to write to "log" the userid that was last written to "users" so each time a user is created, it writes the userid to a log.

I create a trigger on users with a function like the one below...

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_learner_creater() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $log$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO log SELECT userid from users;
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$log$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

So when an insert is fired onto the users table it will return the userid from users, the problem is I don't know what was the last user to be added so this function will not work...

Is there a way to say...

INSERT INTO log SELECT <> from users;

This field in users would be a serial field so would auto-increment (and not be part of the the SQL script in the insert as this would be auto-assigned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to use the `NEW` variable, which contains the new row for which the trigger was invoked (you don't have to `SELECT` for it). Have you looked at the examples from the documentation?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html